# Using trigonometric substitution to integrate $\int\frac{x^3dx}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

[image]

I tried solving this calculus problem so many times but I never got an answer that at least looked similar to the choices in the image. Can someone help?
I don't understand where the Sine came from. This is the answer I get

$$\frac13(25-x^2)^{3/2} - 25\sqrt{25-x^2} + C $$

[image]

Edits are appreciated

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yes I did solve it using the trigonometric substitution method. It's still the same answer

Comment: I edited your answer to display what I think you meant. Can you check that? (maybe the 1/3 was applied to everything?) Also, I didn't obtain your answer, so can you demonstrate how you arrived at it? My answer to the original question is also $d$, but I get a vastly different form than you.

Comment: Just derive the answers b) and c). No use deriving a) since none of the elements would give a square root while deriving. If after simplification, neither the derivatives of b) and c) give the function to be integrated, then the answer is d).

Comment: The logical consequence of your observation is answer D. You could easily integrate  by parts without any sine or its inverse whatsoever.

Comment: @CalvinLin the 1/3 is excluded from the parenthesis.

Comment: @CalvinLin I added an image showing how I reached the answer.

Comment: Your approach is correct. I thought your $(25-x^2)^{3/2}$ was in the denominator, which is why I got a different value from you. I've edited it to reflect your work. I checked my final answer, and it's the same as yours, just factorized differently.

Comment: Some gaming of the question... this is not mathematics but test taking.  You are making the substitution $x = 5 \sin t.$  Which implies that $t = \sin^{-1} \frac x5.$  Looking at the answers, it would be reasonable if the answer had an inverse sine but not for the answer to have a sine function in it.  This lets us eliminate a, c without starting our calculation... but if our answer had an inverse sine it should be $\sin^{-1} \frac x5$ and not $\sin^{-1} x$ eliminating c.  That leaves d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts. Your result is equal to mine, BTW

$$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{25-x^2}} \, dx=\int (-x^2)\,\frac{ -x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\,dx=$$
$$\int \frac{ -x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\,dx=\sqrt{25-x^2}+C$$
$$=-x^2\sqrt{25-x^2}-\int\left(-2x\sqrt{25-x^2}\right)\,dx=$$
$$=-x^2\sqrt{25-x^2}-\frac{2}{3} \left(25-x^2\right)^{3/2}+C=$$
$$=-x^2\sqrt{25-x^2}-\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{25-x^2}(25-x^2)+C=$$
$$=-\sqrt{25-x^2}\left(x^2+\frac{2}{3}(25-x^2)\right)+C=-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{25-x^2} \left(x^2+50\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

You want to evaluate the $$\int \frac{x^3\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}.$$ If you use the substitution $x=5\sin y,$ the integral is transformed into $$125\int \sin^3 y\mathrm dy=-125\int \sin^2y \mathrm d(\cos y)=-125\left(\cos y - \frac{\cos^3y}{3}\right)+\text{constant}.$$

To answer you directly from the solution you obtained, recall that $x=5\sin x,$ so that your result is equivalent to $$\frac{125\cos^3y}{3}-125\cos y+C.$$